# Umbraco Dashboards: custom markup within tabs and specific content page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

In my tab from home page I want to render a partial view returned by an action controller, with custom css. The home page has its own doctype. Using Umbraco v7.

How can I achieve this? I read http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/files-and-folders/dashboardconfig but doesn't specify this.

Answer (score 0):

You can only load a usercontrol (ASCX) in the dashboards.

But that shouldn't stop you from what you want to do.

- Put your Html and css in the ASCX and
- put your controller code in the .cs file.
- update the /config/dashboard.config

And you are set.

What you could do is wrap your partial view in a macro and call the macro inside the ascx (`<umbraco:Macro alias="theMacroAlias" runat="server" />`)

**Update**: you can't set a dashboard for a specific content page.  The only way to archive something here is to create your down propertyType

Comment: thanks Damiaan. First of all how can I load the .ASCX in specific content page tab. E.g. in a tab called Bookings from Homepage?

Comment: that 's the 3rd bullet: update the /config/dashboard.config file.  Just create a new section into the file defining the tab (and usercontrol)

Comment: can this be done using an iframe inside a .html? E.g.`<iframe src="sitename/controller/action"></iframe>` ?

Comment: If you put an iframe inside the usercontrol.  Would not advise to do so.

Comment: Downvoted as it isn't true you can only add .ascx files in a dashboard. You can add any type of file that has a URL. If you look at standard Umbraco 7 /config/Dashboard.config you'll see plenty of examples of dashboards that are HTML views.